# How to find repeat user count in sql query

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a case where I need to find the repeat users count.

Find below the sample data

```
with
fact_table (employee_wid, month, conv_id) as
(select 100024, 'Dec 2022', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100234, 'Dec 2022', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100236, 'Dec 2022', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100024, 'Dec 2022', 'Conv 2' from dual union all
select 100234,'Dec 2022', 'Conv 2' from dual union all
select 100342,'Jan 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100346, 'Jan 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100024, 'Jan 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100024, 'Jan 2023', 'Conv 2' from dual union all
select 100234, 'Jan 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100236, 'Jan 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100236, 'Jan 2023', 'Conv 2' from dual union all
select 100346,'Feb 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100346,'Feb 2023', 'Conv 2' from dual union all
select 100234, 'Feb 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100113,'Feb 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual union all
select 100148,'Feb 2023', 'Conv 1' from dual)
select t.employee_wid,t.month,count(t.conv_id)
from fact_table t
group by t.employee_wid,t.month;
```

Now I need to calculate repeat users.

For eg: Consider month- Dec: 3 unique users are present

for Jan: 4 unique users are present out of which 3 are repetitive user because they have entry in Dec month also

For Feb: 4 unique users are present out of which 2 are repetitive user because they have entry in Jan month.

Expected Output:
Dec 3
Jan 3
Feb 2

Please help me to find the logic

Tried in SQL developer. Wanted to know the logic used

Comment: Can you add the expected output ?

Comment: Year is missing in your data. How to tell  this year months from other year months?

Comment: @SelVazi Added the output

Comment: @Serg actually its the date column where month is extrcted. Will edit it according to year

Comment: Representing month as Jan, Feb... is not useful. Whether you give calendar dates or you give number of month as 1, 2, 3... 12. Otherwise it's a bit complicated to compute the order of those month using a case when month='Jan' then 1 when month='Feb' then 2.... Moreover, that Dec is it from the previous year before Jan or is it the end of the year with Jan?

Comment: @BogdanDincescu have edited the month along with year. Please have a look at it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now it is impossible to say if `Dec` is before `Jan` because there is no information about year in your data. If you change months to `Dec 2022`, `Jan 2023` etc then you can use analytic count with `range` clause:

```
alter session set nls_date_language = 'English';

select month, sum(prev) 
from (
  select employee_wid, t.month, conv_id, 
         count(1) over (partition by employee_wid, conv_id 
                        order by to_date(month, 'Mon-YYYY') 
                        range between interval '1' month preceding 
                                  and interval '1' month preceding) prev
  from fact_table t)
group by month order by to_date(month, 'Mon-YYYY')
```

[dbfiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/Ht1anQlX)

output is:

```
  Dec 2022  0
  Jan 2023  4
  Feb 2023  2
```

---

If you want to count only disintinct ID then use:

```
select month, count(distinct case when prev = 1 then employee_wid end) cnt
```

[dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/g5iYcFow)

---

*... for Dec 2022 month I want the unique user count ...*

```
select month, 
       case row_number() over (order by to_date(month, 'Mon-YYYY')) when 1 then
         count(distinct employee_wid) 
       else 
          count(distinct case when prev = 1 then employee_wid end) 
       end ...
```

Comment: Thanks much for this. One more thing For Dec 2022 month I want the unique user count instead of 0. Any other way to achieve this

Comment: Check if this is the first row, use row_number, like in my edit at bottom.